# netcore 1.0.1 missing .NET v4.0.0.0 but using v5.6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-4.0, database-connection

I use netcore 1.0.1 and want to open a MySqlConnection. 
if I use connection.Open() I get the error:

> The type "DbConnection" is defined in a net referenced Assembly. Add a reference to the assembly"System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".

(Translated from german to english)

In my project.json I import:`

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "net46",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }`
```

what is the reason this does not work? I can not find anything in the Nuget-package manager.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what `imports` does. It basically says "Pretend that I'm actually targeting all these frameworks, so if a package says it supports one of those, it's fine."

Comment: Ok Thank you. I understand this now. Do you have a Idea how I can solve my problem too?

Comment: Adding an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imports` doesn't do what I suspect you think it does - it doesn't actually import anything, but it says "When you're trying to resolve a package, if it doesn't support my *actual* target framework, pretend that I'm targeting these frameworks". You should use it as rarely as possible - ideally not at all. Any time you use it, you're risking this sort of problem.

In terms of `DbConnection`, you need to depend on the [`System.Data.Common`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.Common/) package. It's possible there will be other packages you need too, but that's the one that contains `System.Data.DbConnection`.

However, the `MySql.Data` package supports `netstandard1.6` if you use version 6.10.1-beta or 7.0.7-m61 - and in that case it should pull in `System.Data.Common` anyway.

I suggest you:

- Delete the `imports` part of your `project.json`
- Update to a version of `MySql.Data` that supports .NET Core. (6.9.9 doesn't.)
- Ideally update to the final .NET Core SDK and migrate your `project.json` to `csproj` as well

Comment: Seemed to be the right answer but after adding System.Data.Common the same error still exists

Comment: @tatatoto: Do you still have those imports? If so, you may be pulling in the wrong MySQL assembly - you're claiming to be running in an environment compatible with .NET 4.6 when you're really not...

Comment: The Imports are still the same. I am using MySql.Data v6.9.9

Comment: @tatatoto: So get rid of the imports. I think they're breaking you, basically. In fact, without those I'd expect it to pull in `System.Data.Common` automatically.

Comment: @tatatoto: It looks like you will need to update to 7.0.7-m61 or 6.10.1-beta though - 6.9.9 just doesn't support .NET Core.

Comment: keeping the imports and updating to v6.10.1-beta solved the problem! Thank you

Comment: @tatatoto: I would still *strongly encourage* you to remove those imports. Basically they're lying about the environment you're running in. You may get away with it in some cases, but in others it's covering up problems like the one you've run into.